# Cut the rows and paste in one cell above - Keep Getting Run Time error for the copy and paste areas don't match overlap

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with thousands of rows and multiple columns. The heading of each row is one cell **above** the numbers. For examples

```
My Name     
        2  3 4 5 6
```

[image]

What I want to do is cut from 2 to 6 and paste it up to the last row.

```
 Sub test2()
Dim rOriginalSelection As Range

    Cells.Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
     End With

    Select Case direction
    Case up
        Set rOriginalSelection = Range("B11:O11" & lrow)
    Case Else
        Debug.Assert False
    End Select

    With rOriginalSelection
        .Select
        .Cut
        Select Case direction
        Case "up"
            .Offset(-1, 0).Select
        End Select
    End With
    Selection.Insert
    rOriginalSelection.Select
```

Comment: I am not allowed to post a snapshot yet, but to clarify it. The heading is A10 but actual numbers for that name starts from B11 to X11.

Comment: upload the picture to imgur and paste the link back here.

Comment: https://imgur.com/TQQplI7

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your output? How would you like the data to look like?

Comment: `Range("J11:X11" & lrow)` you don't nee the 11 on the X.  When is `lrow` populated?

Comment: @zedfoxus i want c2 to be c1 till Q. And keep doing the same thing for the rest of the rows.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: @zedfoxus it did. Thank you so very much!

Comment: Outstanding @Shobi! Please feel free to put a closure to your question by marking it as accepted. You are welcome to wait for other answers to arrive also. Your choice. Also, +1 for providing great info to questions asked by commenters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can do that using code like this. It moves one row at a time.

```
Sub Macro1()

    ' We don't know how long the file is. If we find more than 4 consequent
    ' empty cells in column A, we should stop looping
    Dim EmptyCellCount As Integer

    ' Row number to start from
    Dim MyRow As Integer

    EmptyCellCount = 0
    MyRow = 1

    Do While EmptyCellCount < 5

        ' select A1 and check if there's any content in it
        Range("A" & MyRow).Select

        If Len(Trim(Range("A" & MyRow).Text)) > 0 Then

            ' select content from the next line and put in the current line
            Range("C" & MyRow + 1 & ":Q" & MyRow + 1).Select
            Selection.Cut
            Range("C" & MyRow).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            ' switch to the next row and reset empty cell count
            MyRow = MyRow + 1
            EmptyCellCount = 0

        Else

            ' switch to the next row and increment empty cell count
            MyRow = MyRow + 1
            EmptyCellCount = EmptyCellCount + 1

        End If

    Loop
End Sub
```

This one moves the entire block one row up

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim EmptyCellCount As Integer
    Dim MyRow As Integer
    MyRow = 1

    ' Find the cell where the last A cell is filled, approximately
    Do While EmptyCellCount < 3
        If Len(Trim(Range("A" & MyRow).Text)) > 0 Then
            EmptyCellCount = 0
        Else
            EmptyCellCount = EmptyCellCount + 1
        End If
        MyRow = MyRow + 1
    Loop

    ' Move the entire block up one row
    Range("C2:Q" & MyRow).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```